# MVC Change Landing Page is not working: Options.Conventions.AddPageRoute(

Tags: c#, html, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I tried changing the landing page of my web page Mvc application using this command. However it is still redirecting me to regular index, not Products/Index. How would I resolve this?

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        var connection = @"Server=localhost;Database=Electronics;Trusted_Connection=True;ConnectRetryCount=0";
        services.AddDbContext<ElectronicsContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));
        services.AddTransient<IProductRepository<Product>, ProductRepository>();
        services.AddTransient<IProductCategoryRepository<ProductCategory>, ProductCategoryRepository>();
        services.AddTransient<ICustomerRepository<Customer>, CustomerRepository>();
        services.AddTransient<ISupplyRepository<Supply>, SupplyRepository>();
        services.AddScoped<ShoppingCartRepository>(sp => ShoppingCartSession.GetCart(sp));
        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

        services.AddAutoMapper();

        services.AddMvc().AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
        {
            options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Products/Index", "");
        }).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

        services.AddMemoryCache();
        services.AddSession();

        services.AddSingleton<IMemoryContainer,MemoryContainer>();
        services.AddSingleton(new LoggerFactory().AddConsole().AddDebug());
        services.AddLogging();
        _logger.LogInformation("configure services log");

    }
```

Comment: So you are changing the default root folder?

Answer (score 0):

If you have an Index.cshtml file with an underlying Index.cshtml.cs page controller, add the following method to it:

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{

    public IActionResult OnGet()
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Products");
    }
}
```

I've just spent hours trying to figure this one out...